# is removeFromSuperview releases the object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am using `removeFromSuperview` for removing a view from its superview. I am also using `release` after `removeFromSuperview` on that object, sometimes its work fine but sometimes give bad access.

is `removeFromSuperview` also call `release` to the object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `removeFromSuperview` also releases view.

You need to release your view after you have added it to its superview.

```
CGRect frame; // let's assume you already have defined frame and superview
UIView *superview;

UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[superview addSubview:subview];
[subview release];
```

Or just use `autorelease`, when you create a view.

```
UIView *subview = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
[superview addSubview:subview];
```

In both cases, you don't need to call `release` after you call `removeFromSuperview`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, addSubview calls retain, and removeFromSuperview calls release. So your call to release does not belong there (it probably belongs after you assign the subview, assuming you do not want to hold the object).

Answer (score 0):

Actually `removeFromSuperview` decreases the `retainCount` property of the view Object and so as the `release`.

So,if you do the way Aleksejs said.

```
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[superview addSubview:subview];
[subview release];
```

`subview` -> `alloc`= `retainCount` = +1 ,

`subview` -> `addSubView` =  `retainCount = +1`

`subview` -> `release` = `retainCount` = -1.

`subview` -> `removeFromSuperView` =  `retainCount = -1`

(subview removed from memory)

Comment: Absolute retain counts are useless (and -retainCount can never return zero).  Think in terms of deltas.

Comment: for more info on why they are useless, see note https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571952-retaincount?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is "probably". This is an implementation detail that you shouldn't even really be thinking about. If your code needs to work with the subview, then you should be retaining it before you start working on it, and you should be releasing it when you're finished working with it (which may or may not coincide with removing it from it's superview).

I imagine testing would show that removeFromSuperview does release the view, but you cannot depend on this behaviour and should never assume it will happen. Even if it does always happen now it might not in future.

You shouldn't even need to think about memory management at such a low level as this. If you retain the object with `retain` or `copy` or `alloc` or `new` then you are responsible for counter-acting that with a `release` at some point in the future.

If you did not do any of these things, then you should not be releasing it. The methods for adding a subview to a view do not contain `retain` or `copy` in their name and therefore you are *not* supposed to release it yourself when you remove it from it's superview.

The view system is very complicated, especially on an iPhone with such a limited amount of RAM and not inadequate storage to use virtual memory. Stick to the rules and you should be fine. Or enable ARC.